# Gráfico criado incorretamente

Tags: html, python, pandas, gráfico, matplotlib

Olá,

Eu estou treinando a criação de gráficos no Python com matplotlib. Para isso, estou importando um HTML com histórico de ações da WEGE3.

```
df_history = pd.read_html("https://br.financas.yahoo.com/quote/WEGE3.SA/history?p=WEGE3.SA")
```

Tirei os duplicados (só haviam 2):

```
df_remove = df_history[0].drop_duplicates(subset=['Data'])
```

E tirei a última linha:

```
yy = df_remove['Fechamento*'].drop(100)
xx = df_remove['Data'].drop(100)
```

Defini as labels:

```
plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('Preço')
```

**O problema acontece aqui:** Quando eu vou exibir o gráfico, ele fica errado. Eu aumentei o tamanho só para eu ver se os valores de X e Y apareciam corretos no grafico e aparecem, mas o desenho do gráfico mesmo, está errado:

```
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(28) 
f.set_figheight(28)
plt.plot(xx, yy) 
plt.show()
```

Este é o gráfico (errado) que aparece:
[image: Gráfico errado]

Para confirmar se o gráfico está certo ou errado, eu peguei os mesmo dados e coloquei no Excel.

Este seria o gráfico correto:

[image: Gráfico correto]

Eu perdi um tempo tentando analisar mas eu não encontrei onde está o problema.

Não sei se esta informação é relevante mas, eu estou executando este código no Google Colab.

Obrigado.

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer o gráfico a partir  do [csv](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/WEGE3.SA?period1=1577853285&period2=1609475685&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true) disponibilizado na própria página de HTML importada?

Comment: Com o CVS deu certo. Mas como meu objetivo é treinar, eu gostaria de entender o meu erro usando o HTML mesmo :)

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que tanto `xx` quanto `yy` estão preenchidos com *strings*, ao invés de valores numéricos ou de data. Por isso, quando você plota, *matplotlib* só está vendo texto. Para resolver, basta converter para os tipos adequados:

1. `yy` pode ser convertido para uma série de inteiros usando o método `to_numeric()`. Precisa também usar o argumento `errors='coerce'`, porque tem alguns valores não disponíveis que não podem ser convertidos diretamente para inteiro.
2. `xx` está com a data escrita por extenso, em português. Talvez funcione num programa como o excel (se ele estiver em português), mas pra converter pra um formato de data que o python entenda você teria que criar uma função dedicada. A alternativa é usar os valores como estão, aí a função `plot()` vai usá-los como *labels* do eixo x.

O código fica assim:

```
# define um tamanho maior para a figura, caso contrário fica impossível de ler os labels
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))

# plot com os valores de xx no eixo x e yy convertido para inteiros no eixo y
plt.plot(xx, pd.to_numeric(yy, errors='coerce'))

# rotação de 60 graus dos labels para tornar legível
plt.xticks(rotation = 60)

# mostra a figura
plt.show()
```

Resulta na seguinte figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que ficou com uma descontinuidade, referente a um dia em que não tinha a cotação disponível (o argumento `errors='coerce'` fez que fosse convertido para *NaN*).